# Add new columns to a existing database througt doctrine command Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I need help, I'm working in symfony, adn I created a database with 3 tables, but now I need to add some new columns into the tables, I created a new properties on the entity that I want to add them (new columns) into my tables. I installed the migrations Bundle but it doesn't work, I tried the schema uopdate as the documentation said and then I tried the migrations:diff and then the Migrate, and it seems like there is no changes to add to the entity/table, I'm very lost, could someone guide me please ? Is the private $usuario;

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Usuario", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="usuario_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $usuario;
```

Comment: Please add the generated migration.

Comment: when you do schema update you cant use migration diff any more because it does create the column after creating new column just do the migration diff and then migration migrate it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to make the changes to your Entity and save it. Verify the changes have been made.

Then from the command prompt run:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Out of the box on a Symfony 4.2.x app this should work with no issues.